# Function that allows to match an observation of one variable to another observation in another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm looking for a function that allows me to match an observation from one variable to an observation from a different variable.

For example, I have a variable called "nbagameid" that identifies a unique nba game and another variable call "charter" identifying which person (charter A and charter B) charted which nba game. I'd like to find where Charter A and B charted the same game. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of doing it, but I would: filter out everyone but Charter A and B; count how many times the nba game apears, and then and filter for 2 appearances.

```
df %>%
filter(charter=="charter A"| charter=="charter B") %>%
count(nbagameid) %>%
filter(n==2)
```

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seem like the code is returning the filtered data set for me. The charter column only has two charters A and B.

Comment: Okay cool, you can just skip the filtering step in that case?